# Convert unicode code points to alphabetical strings in Python

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, utf-8

I have a list of unicode code points like

```
<U+041D><U+041C><U+0418><U+0426> <U+041D><U+0435><U+0439><U+0440><U+043E><U+0445><U+0438><U+0440><U+0443><U+0440><U+0433><U+0438><U+0438> <U+0438><U+043C>. <U+041D>,<U+041D>.<U+0411><U+0443><U+0440><U+0434><U+0435><U+043D><U+043A><U+043E>
```

How do I convert these to a regular string - they represent a particular string like 'hello'

Comment: So, do you have string `"<U+041D><U+041C><U+0418>..."` and want convert it to regular unicode string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regular expressions to identify unicode points. Extract the hexadecimal number from each point, convert it to decimal, and map to the character with that code:

```
import re

def decoder(match):
    code = match.group(1) # The code in hex
    return chr(int(code, 16))

uni = # Your string
re.sub("<U\+([0-9a-fA-F]+)>", decoder, uni)
#'НМИЦ Нейрохирургии им. Н,Н.Бурденко'
```